# How to calculate database disk blocks?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, block

I am doing some prep form my DB final and am stack with this question. I have the answer but I am not sure that my steps are correct. Would appreciate if you can tell me if my answers have the correct logic in them. Thanks

> Assume that the EMPLOYEE table has 2000 tuples. It has a primary key
>   column called ID that has a range of [1 - 2000]. It also has an column
>   called DOB (date of birth). There are 250 distinct DOB values among
>   the employees (i.e., on average four employees share the same DOB).
>   Assume that 20 EMPLOYEE tuples can fit into a disk block. Each
>   scenario given below is independent, that is because ID is indexed in
>   one scenario does not mean it is indexed in the others.
>
> Assume that EMPLOYEE has a sparse, B+-tree index on the ID attribute.
>   Each node in the index has a maximum fanout of 100 (each node in the
>   tree can have 100 children). Each node in the index is 50% full. (a)
>   How many disk blocks does the index occupy? (b) The following query
>   will read how many disk blocks in the worst case (give an exact
>   number, e.g., 50)?
>
> SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = 80;
>
> (c) The following query will read how many disk blocks? Note that this
>   query projects the ID.
>
> SELECT ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID > 1500;
>
> (d)
>   The following query will read how many disk blocks?
>
> ```
>       SELECT MAX(ID)
>       FROM EMPLOYEE;
> ```

A)My take on this is that if there are 100 entries in the index(20000/200), 50 in each block. So 2 blocks for entries and one root block.

B) Because it is a sparse index, it will read one block on top level to figures out which of the lover ones to go, and then one of the lower blocks to find the correct values. so it will read 2 blocks in worst case

C) 2 blocks. One to find number 1500, another to find all the tuples >1500

D) 3 blocks. 2 to find the max value block, another to find max value itself.

> Assume that EMPLOYEE has a single-level, dense, clustering index on
>   DOB. Assume that each node in the index can hold 200 index records.
>   (a) How many disk blocks does the index occupy?
>
> (b) The following
>   query will read how many disk blocks in the worst case (give an exact
>   number, e.g., 50)?
>             SELECT ID
>             FROM EMPLOYEE
>             WHERE ID = 80;
>
> (c)The following query will read how many disk blocks? Note that this query projects the DOB.
>
> SELECT DOB FROM
>   EMPLOYEE WHERE DOB <> ’1/1/2000’;
>
> (d) The following query will read
>   how many disk blocks?
>
> SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DOB = ’1/1/2000’’;

A) 3 Blocks again. One root, one with 200 entries one with 50

B) Since ID is not indexed in this example, it has to looks through whole table. But I am not sure how to calculate the blocks.

C) 3 Blocks? Whole table must be scanned.

D) 2 lower level blocks to find the indexes

Sorry for the long post, just tried to add all the details.